# php header redirect back with + adding something

Tags: php, post, header

can i add to this script something like this:

`header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'&msg=Thanks for submiting'); //edited`

that i can redirect the user + adding something to the link?

Comment: what you want??? &msg=Thanks+for+something  ??

Comment: to add a message when you go back

Comment: This is very easy to try, isn't it?

Comment: ok than its easy just take a variable &msg or ?id=msg and than on php page check if($_GET['msg']){ echo "Thanks for submiting"; }

Comment: if you are using single variable in URL then add "?" instead of "&", also for message use urlencode() and urldecode() functions

Comment: is there a trick for useing ? or &    ?msg=Thanks for submiting or &msg=Thanks for submiting automaticly where needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. This is the right syntax:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?msg=Thanks for submiting');
```

You can also use double quotes (variable will be expanded):

```
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}?msg=Thanks for submiting");
```

Please notice that if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` already has some parameters, you should use `&` instead of `?`.

Of course, remember to to handle/display the `$_GET['msg']` content on the page you're redirecting to.

Comment: is there a trick for useing ? or &  ?msg=Thanks for submiting or &msg=Thanks for submiting where needed?

Comment: a simple regex check could be enough to choose the right syntax

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?&msg=Thanks for submitting";
header("Location: {$url}");
```

Also, if you want to redirect after some seconds, add `refresh: timetowait`.

Answer (score 0):

you have not concatenate url string correctly.try this

```
 header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'&msg=Thanks for submiting');
```